Is It Possible to Override Behavior of ons-button-back But Keep Default Animation?
I'm working on a small single page application in Onsen UI.  It presents multiple screens that collect form data, all of which gets submitted to a mySql database on the backend on the last page template.  As users are free to move back and forth through previously loaded templates, I've overridden the behavior of the Onsen back button to bring a previously visited page to the top of the navigation stack, rather than pop it off the stack.  This is working, but I'd like to maintain the default animation of the back button.  What is currently happening is I'm getting the same animation effect that occurs by default when a regular Onsen button is clicked.  Is it possible to maintain the default back button animation behavior (e.g., slide out vs. slide in)?
If not, I'm wondering if it would be possible to define my own class that inherits most of the behavior from ons-back-button, but overrides just the stack navigation behavior (bring a page to the top of the stack rather than popping it)?  I haven't really worked with the new ES6 classes yet, so thought I'd ask here before trying that approach.
Here's the current code I'm using for the back button:
document.querySelector('ons-back-button').onClick = function() {
   previous('page1.html');       
};

function previous(page){
    const prevNav = document.querySelector('#navigator');
    prevNav.bringPageTop(page);
}
      

And here's the navigator element HTML:
<ons-splitter>
    <ons-splitter-side id="menu" side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
        <ons-page>
            <ons-list>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page1.html')" tappable>Vehicle Information</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page2.html')" tappable>Exterior Damage</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page3.html')" tappable>Glovebox Check</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page4.html')" tappable>Interior Check</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page5.html')" tappable>Road Test</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page6.html')" tappable>Lights Check</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page7.html')" tappable>Fluid Inspection</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('page8.html')" tappable>Tire Inspection</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item onclick="fn.load('signature.html')" tappable>Signature</ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-splitter-side>
    <ons-splitter-content id="content">
        <ons-navigator animation="slide" animation-options="{ duration: 0.3 }" id="navigator" page="page1.html">        
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-splitter-content>
</ons-splitter>


How about using addEventListener? Instead of overwriting the value (the function) of the button's onclick property one would register this very function as handler to the button's 'click'-listener ... like e.g. ... document.querySelector('ons-back-button').addEventListener('click', evt => previous('page1.html') };. Whenever a 'click' event occurs, the original onclick function gets invoked as usual, but on top the additionally registered handler function will be executed as well.

Thanks Peter - I think I tried it that way as well and the animation also was changing, but I'll give it another try and double-check.

That ALMOST worked...I subbed out the 'previous' function I was calling with a simple function that just displays an alert, and I got the animation behavior I was expecting! But when I call my 'previous' function, I'm seeing the default ons-button animation.  I think the animations are associated with the onsen navigator methods (popPage(), bringPageTop()) rather than the buttons.  I'm not great at CSS animations - I was looking in the source code for Onsen UI yesterday and found the relevant sections of the code.  I'll look a bit more today to try to figure out how the animations are working.
